# When looking for zeros of a rational function, why is the numerator equated to zero and not the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, rational-functions

If you have a function $F(x)=\dfrac{a(x)}{b(x)}$ and you are asked to find the zero(s) of the function, why do you set the numerator equal to zero, and not the denominator?

Comment: If $\;b=0\;$ then you don't have an actual mathematical expression here: it **must** be that $\;b\neq 0\;$ , and then the fraction equals zero iff $\;a=0\;$

Answer (score 2):

The quotient

$$\frac{a}{b} = c$$

if there exists a unique number $c$ such that $a = bc$.

If $b = 0$, the quotient $a/b$ is undefined. To see this, consider cases.

**Case 1:** If $a \neq 0$ and $b = 0$, then

$$\frac{a}{b} = c \Rightarrow  a = b \cdot c = 0 \cdot c = 0$$

contradicting our hypothesis that $a \neq 0$.  Hence, if $a \neq 0$, the quotient does not exist.

**Case 2:**  If $a = b = 0$, then $c = 0$ satisfies the equation $a = bc$ since $0 = 0 \cdot 0$.  However, so does $c = 1$ since $0 = 0 \cdot 1$.  Thus, the quotient is not uniquely defined.

Hence,

$$F(x) = \frac{a}{b}$$

is only defined if $b \neq 0$.  If $F(x)$ is defined, then

$$F(x) = \frac{a}{b} = 0 \Rightarrow a = b \cdot 0 = 0$$

so $F(x)$ is only equal to zero if $a = 0$ and $b \neq 0$.

Comment: You can have $a(x) = 0$ and $b(x) = 0$ at some point where the order of  the zero of $a$ at that point is greater than or equal to the order of the zero of $b = 0 at that point. Am I missing something?

Comment: If that occurs, the function has a removable discontinuity at the point.  For instance, the function $$f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 3x - 4}{x - 4} = \frac{(x + 1)(x - 4)}{x - 4} = x + 1$$ provided that $x \neq 4$.  It has a removable discontinuity at the point $(4, 5)$ since \begin{align*} \lim_{x \to 4} f(x) & = \lim_{x \to 4} \frac{x^2 - 3x - 4}{x - 4}\\ & = \lim_{x \to 4} x + 1\\ & = 4 + 1\\ & = 5\end{align*}  A removable discontinuity corresponds to a hole in the graph of the function.

Comment: Ah! Yes. I was thinking wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Because $a/b = 0$ if and only if $b\neq 0$ and $a=0$ .

If $b=0$, the expression $\frac ab$ is not defined.

Take a look at some examples.

- Is $\frac01=0$? Yes, because $0$ divided by $1$ is $0$.
- Is $\frac10=0$ ? No, because $\frac10$ is not a number.

Comment: You meant "because $0$ divided by $1$ is $0$" rather than "because $0$ divided by $0$ is $0$."

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Indeed. Thank you, I fixed my answer.